# "real world" JSON transformation using immutable javascript/node

Tags: javascript, node.js, immutability

**Background**

I transformed a non-trivial JSON response that uses arrays into

- a nested object
- eliminating some of the original properties
- inserting a new summary property that is a unique list of values from the original object

I did this with temporary variables, foreach loops and some conditional logic.  My first working code, sample input / output JSON are below.

**Question / Concern**

While this works, I'm concerned about the "smell" of the code and the maintainability.  Is there a way to do this that would be more maintainable (perhaps with Array. ..., map, filter, reduce) ?  I'm not looking for a working solution but more than "one liners".

**CODE**

```
const raw = require('./tests/data/raw.json');

function parseLoc(loc) {
  const types = new Set();

  // constant properties with loc_id the name of the object
  let o = { [loc.loc_id]: { last_update: loc.last_update, type_id: loc.type_id } };
  types.add(loc.type_id);
  // optional property
  if (loc.contents) {
    o = { [loc.loc_id]: { ...o[loc.loc_id], contents: loc.contents } };
    loc.contents.forEach((item) => {
      types.add(item.type_id); // can have nested types
    });
  }
  // optional property
  if (loc.plan_id) {
    o = { [loc.loc_id]: { ...o[loc.loc_id], plan_id: loc.plan_id } };
  }
  // summary properties
  o = {
    [loc.loc_id]: {
      ...o[loc.loc_id],
      Types: [...types],
    },
  };
  return o;
}

const driver = () => {
  const { locs } = raw[Object.keys(raw)[0]];

  let out = {};
  locs.forEach((loc) => {
    const t = parseLoc(loc);
    out = { ...out, [Object.keys(t)[0]]: t[Object.keys(t)[0]] };
  });
  console.log('out', out);
};

driver();
```

**Input**

```
   {
  "Input": {
    "locs": [
      {
        "contents": [{ "amount": 1, "type_id": 2393 }],
        "last_update": "2013-09-22T21:53:51Z",
        "obsolete1": 1.52384062551,
        "obsolete2": 1.56361060962,
        "loc_id": 1011160470678,
        "type_id": 2524
      },
      {
        "last_update": "2019-07-29T10:56:27Z",
        "obsolete1": 1.60921860432,
        "obsolete2": 1.60545414964,
        "loc_id": 1028580652821,
        "plan_id": 97,
        "type_id": 2474
      },
      {
        "contents": [
          { "amount": 560, "type_id": 2393 },
          { "amount": 560, "type_id": 9838 },
          { "amount": 560, "type_id": 2317 },
        ],
        "last_update": "2019-02-28T22:09:51Z",
        "obsolete1": 1.55924075537,
        "obsolete2": 1.58171860958,
        "loc_id": 1029669382563,
        "type_id": 2544
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{
  "Output": {
    "types": [2393, 9838, 2524, 2474, 2312],
    "locs": {
      "1011160470678": {
        "last_update": "2013-09-22T21:53:51Z",
        "type_id": 2524
      },
      "1028580652821": {
        "contents": [{ "amount": 560, "type_id": 9838 }],
        "last_update": "2019-07-29T10:56:27Z",
        "plan_id": 97,
        "type_id": 2474
      },
      "1029669382563": {
        "contents": [
          { "amount": 560, "type_id": 2393 },
          { "amount": 560, "type_id": 9838 },
          { "amount": 560, "type_id": 2317 }
        ],
        "last_update": "2019-02-28T22:09:51Z",
        "type_id": 2544
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you post what you have tried, showing the expected output, and explain why what you have does not work? If it works, it's not a good fit for SO. Maybe it's mutating and you don't want to mutate? It's always best to show what you have tried. Otherwise we are just writing code for you!

Comment: Juan, ... thanks for taking the time to read my post.  I've edited it and included working code.

Comment: Timothy, as I mentioned, if it works, it's not a good fit for StackOverflow. How about https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ? Having said that, it looks readable to me and I don't think map, filter and reduce would make it more maintainable. It may make it more elegant, but potentially harder to understand.

Comment: Thanks again for your input.  I did take your suggestion and posted this on codereview.

Comment: Link to codereview post: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/225849/real-world-json-transformation-using-javascript-node-is-there-a-better-approa (also, +1 for `{[someKeyishValue]: 'Hello' }` syntax, I didn't know one can do that)

Comment: I think of the square brackets when used like that as a dereference operator (*) from my old "C" days.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network https://codereview.stackexchange.com/